# What would you call this fenced training area for horses?

Tags: terminology, image-identification, animals

[image: a rider on his horse (trotting) in a large area of land, enclosed by a fence]

What would you call this fenced area used for training horses?

Comment: It's a *paddock*

Comment: [ODO]() has  << **paddock** _noun_ 

1 A small field or enclosure where horses are kept or exercised. >>. But this is obviously a hypernym. 'Fenced training area for horses' works reasonably well, but 'paddock' is less of a mouthful.

Comment: In the American West it is also called a _corral_.

Comment: Our county fairgrounds calls it an arena. Basically a gussied up paddock, though.

Comment: "I'm riding in the ring." -NJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paddock is defined by [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paddock) as:

> a small, usually enclosed field near a stable or barn for pasturing or exercising animals.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't as simple as it appears; it looks from your picture as if the area has a specific covering of sawdust or bark, which provides better traction for hooves as well as a softer surface to fall on if the trainee is recalcitrant. (Many establishments use old car tyres minced up: I suppose it's one form of recycling).

This means it is not a *paddock*, which is an ordinary field that can be used for training, or a *corral*, which is a fenced area where horses are kept before being transported (or, of course, where John Wayne turned his horse out while he had a drink in the saloon: perhaps some American contributor can say if this is still in use).

In some places, as Andy says, this is called a *manege* and the establishment it is part of is called a *school* or *riding school*; in others the establishment is called a [manege](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/manege) and the area is called a *school*, possibly a 'sand school' or `outdoor school' if it is necessary to be specific. There are of course *schooling rings* and *training grounds*, which usually have some facilities such as letters at intervals round the outside.

Ultimately, it depends how specific you want to be and how horse-knowledgeable your audience is: "a horse-training area" is perfectly comprehensible.

Comment: I was recently at the Grand Canyon, where they do trips by mule into the canyon. I (and [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=grand+canyon+corral&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=m4IEWsjLJMyq8weDtpTwAg&gws_rd=ssl)) can confirm that the place where the mules were held was definitely referred to as a corral by all the signage. PS I've now deleted my answer as yours covers the same ground but with a lot of additional info.